# How to define a varying length of the string in XSD pattern?

Tags: xsd

The input XML tag must be validated for a pattern which is like this:

```
type : positive int / decimal
minimum length is 0
max length is 12(before decimal point)
fraction digits are optional if exist then precision must be 2.
```

This means both positive integer and Decimal numbers(2 digit precision) are allowed.

so the acceptable values can be like:

- null
- 0
- 0.00
- 1234567890
- 123456789012
- 123456789012.12

invalid values are:

- 0.000
- 1234567890123 (13 digits - invalid)

The pattern I have designed is:

```
<xs:pattern value="|([0-9]){12}|([0-9]){12}[.][0-9][0-9]"/>
```

The problem with this pattern is, it doesn't allow the number with string-length less than 12, it says "1234567890" is an invalid value, where as it must be allowed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex pattern `\d{0,12}(\.\d{2})?` should do the trick.

A short explanation of the pattern:

`\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`. `\d{0,12}` indicates that `\d` should occur 0 to 12 times. It is greedy, so it will try to match as many as it can, up to 12.

`\.\d{2}` represents a dot followed by exactly two digits.

`?` indicates that the previous item can occur 0 or 1 time. The brackets around `(\.\d{2})` are necessary because without them `?` would apply only to `\d{2}`

Answer (score 1):

But the above would allow:

`.00` as valid input. Perhaps something like: `(|\d{1,12}(\.\d{2})?)` to allow null or at least a single digit would be better.